# Tornado request handler mapping to international characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode, tornado

I want to be able to match URL requests for some internationalized characters, like `/Comisión`. This is my setup:

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [ 
            '''some handlers, and then this: '''
            (r"/([\w\:\,]+)", InternationalizedHandler)
            ]
            tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

But setting locales in Tornado doesn't seem to be the right solution. How is it possible to set up the regex to catch characters such as *é,å,µ* etc.? Will changing the `re` mode in python do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It's impossible to do with Tornado's built-in router.

Tornado buries the regexp compiling for handler patterns pretty deep, so @stema's suggestion to use the `re.Unicode` flag is difficult, because it's not immediately clear where to pass in the flag. There are two ways to tackle that particular problem: subclass `URLSpec` and override the `__init__` function, or put a flag prefix in the pattern.

The first option is a lot of work. The second option takes advantage of a feature in Python's `re` module in which patterns may specify `(?u)` at the beginning of the pattern instead of passing in the `re.UNICODE` flag as a parameter.

Unfortunately, neither option will work since Tornado matches patterns against the request URL *before* percent-decoding it into the unicode string. Therefore, compiling the pattern with the Unicode flag has no effect since you're matching against percent-encoded ASCII URLs, not Unicode strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you look here you see what your expression "means": http://regex101.com/r/zO9zC8

If you want to match `é,å,µ`, you need to match the inverse of `a-zA-Z0-9`, which would be `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`. Seeing as how you used `\w` prior, you may aswell use `\W` which is the same as `[^\w]`.

Good luck!

Edit:
Re-reading your question I suggest you follow @stemas answer instead.